# How can i change the position of a data in a data field in mongoDB?

Tags: python, database, mongodb, datafield

I am learning a mongoDB right now and to progress on my project I wanted to be able to change the position of a data inside a a data field.
For example:

**FROM**

```
{"Student_No": "1", "Last_Name": "Jain", "First_Name": "Rohan"}
```

**TO**

```
{"Student_No": "1", "First_Name": "Rohan", "Last_Name": "Jain"}
```

---

So basically I just want to change the position of the data as shown above

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: But why? It doesn't make a difference where it is.

Comment: i understand what ur trying to say, but i have made a huge mistake and i want to change the position of 2 data, the collection is too big to change or update it one by one

Comment: But it doesn't make a difference to your output. I'd say don't waste your time with this and get on with what you are actually supposed to do.